# How to replace values in a numpy array based on another column?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let say i have the following:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([
     [1,2,3],
     [1,2,3],
     [1,2,3],
     [4,5,6],         
     ])
```

How would I go about changing values in column 3 based on values in column 2?  For instance, If column 3 == 3, column 2 = 9.

```
[[1,9,3],
 [1,9,3],
 [1,9,3],
 [4,5,6]]
```

I've looked at `np.any()`, but I can't figure out how to alter the array in place.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [Numpy's slicing and indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) to achieve this. Take all the rows where the third column is `3`, and change the second column of each of those rows to `9`:

```
>>> data[data[:, 2] == 3, 1] = 9
>>> data
array([[1, 9, 3],
       [1, 9, 3],
       [1, 9, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

Comment: Does this copy the data, or does it alter data in place without reserving additional memory?

Comment: @Barbarossa: It alters the data in place, although additional memory is required to make the index with `data[:, 2] == 3`.