# Change Values in One Array, Based On Value from Column of Second Array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a one dimensional array called `Y_train` that contains a series of 1's and 0's. I have another array called `sample_weight` that is an array of all 1's that has the shape of `Y_train`, defined as:

```
sample_weight = np.ones(Y_train.shape, dtype=int)
```

I'm trying to change the values in `sample_weight` to a `2`, where the corresponding value in `Y_train == 0`. So initially side by side it looks like:

```
Y_train        sample_weight
0              1
0              1
1              1
1              1
0              1
1              1
```

and I'd like it to look like this after the transformation:

```
Y_train        sample_weight
0              2
0              2
1              1
1              1
0              2
1              1
```

What I tried was to use a `for` loop (shown below) but none of the 1's are changing to 2's in `sample_weight`. I'd like to somehow use the `np.where()` function if possible, but it's not crucial, just would like to avoid a `for` loop:

```
sample_weight = np.ones(Y_train.shape, dtype=int)
for num, i in enumerate(Y_train):
    if i == 0:
        sample_weight[num] == 2
```

I tried using the solution shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20355311/how-to-replace-values-in-a-numpy-array-based-on-another-column) but to no success with the second array. Any ideas??? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

Y_train = np.array([0,0,1,1,0,1])
sample_weight = np.where(Y_train == 0, 2, Y_train)

>> print(sample_weight)
[2 2 1 1 2 1]
```

The `np.where` basically works just like Excel's "IF":

`np.where(condition, then, else)`

Works for transposed arrays, too:

```
Y_train = np.array([[0,0,1,1,0,1]]).T
sample_weight = np.where(Y_train == 0, 2, Y_train)

>> print(sample_weight)
[[2]
 [2]
 [1]
 [1]
 [2]
 [1]]
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, and thank you for the quick lesson on where(). I learned proper syntax now. Thanks!